# second shortest / k-th shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

With the code below, I am trying to find the second shortest path / k-th shortest path.

```
// Run Dijkstra's algorithm on given graph
    public static void shortestPath(GraphModel graph, int source, int destination, int numberOfVertices)
    {
        // create min heap and push source node having distance 0
        PriorityQueue<NodeModel> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((lhs, rhs) -> lhs.weight - rhs.weight);
        minHeap.add(new NodeModel(source, 0));

        // set infinite distance from source to v initially
        List<Integer> dist = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(numberOfVertices, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        // distance from source to itself is zero
        dist.set(source, 0);

        // boolean array to track vertices for which minimum
        // cost is already found
        boolean[] done = new boolean[numberOfVertices];
        done[0] = true;

        // stores predecessor of a vertex (to print path)
        int prev[] = new int[numberOfVertices];
        prev[0] = -1;

        // run till minHeap is not empty
        while (!minHeap.isEmpty())
        {
            // Remove and return best vertex
            NodeModel node = minHeap.poll();
            node = minHeap.poll();
            // get vertex number
            int u = node.vertex;

            // do for each neighbor v of u
            for (EdgeModel edge: graph.adjList.get(u))
            {
                int v = edge.dest;
                int weight = edge.weight;
                // Relaxation step
                if (!done[v] && (dist.get(u) + weight) < dist.get(v))
                {
                    dist.set(v, dist.get(u) + weight);
                    prev[v] = u;
                    minHeap.add(new NodeModel(v, dist.get(v)));
                }
            }

            // marked vertex u as done so it will not get picked up again
            done[u] = true;
        }
```

Here is the graph.

```
    List<EdgeModel> edges = Arrays.asList(
            new EdgeModel(0, 1, 10), 
            new EdgeModel(0, 4, 3),
            new EdgeModel(1, 2, 5), 
            new EdgeModel(1, 4, 1),
            new EdgeModel(2, 3, 7), 
            new EdgeModel(2, 4, 8),
            new EdgeModel(3, 4, 2), 
            new EdgeModel(4, 1, 20)
    );
```

> The shortest path from 0-4 is 3
>
> The second shortest path from 0-4 is 11

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the Yen's Algorithm. This Algorithm is used to find the k-th shortest paths(multiple paths) for single source and single destination.The algorithm assumes that you have found the shortest path using Djikstra or any other Algorithm. Here is the link for your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could check all path from A node to B node using `Depth First Traversal` algorithm. Then get two shortest one or 2nd the shortest path. Tell me if it was helpful.

Comment: You could use `Depth First Traversal` for matching all paths. Then calculate distance for every path. You could use your own algorithm, dijkstra, Bellman-Ford or sth else.

Comment: although getting all of the paths would work, its also very expensive. O(2^n) not the solution i need

Answer (score 0):

You can update Dijkstra to do that, you just need to remember two values - shortest and second shortest. Basically, as you go through graph you compare and save two values. Shortest is same, second one is as folowing :

- no second one, save new value when comparing
- better path - save existing path to second value
- not better path, but better than existing second - replace second one

You will have to take your second value - once it exists everywhere with you in same manner as shortest one

Comment: this would happen within the relaxation, i assume?

Comment: would you mind providing some pseudocode for this? how would this work for kth shortest?

Comment: Yes, you need to add there if-statements for second value and in general field and logic for second value.

Comment: I am not at the computer atm, but I can provide some code in 8 hours

Comment: It's kind of vague, but I'm pretty sure this answer doesn't describe a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

The Kth shortest path is the shortest path that deviates from all of the K-1 shorter paths (there may be ties -- break them arbitrarily).

To find the Kth shortest path:

First, run Dijkstra's algorithm starting at the target on the graph with reversed edges, to find the distance from each vertex to the target in log-linear time.  For each vertex, this lets you immediately determine the length of the shortest path from that vertex, and easily find it.

Then, put the shortest path into a trie.  This is the 1st shortest path.

Then, for 2..K, the task is to add the shortest path that is NOT in the trie.  This path will *deviate* from the trie in at some point.  That means it will have an edge that does *not* follow a path in the trie, but which *starts* on a path in the trie.  So:

- Iterate through all the nodes in the trie, and examine the edges not taken at that node by any path -- each one represents a deviation.
- For each deviation, calculate the length of the shortest path that uses it.  This is easy in constant time, since you already have the distances.
- Remember the deviation corresponding to the shortest new path, and add the shortest path containing that deviation to the trie.

The last path you add to the trie is the Kth-shortest one.

As written, this takes O((K + log V)(V+E)) time, which is not too bad.  If you maintain the deviations in a priority queue instead of searching for them every time, then you can to it in O(KV+E log E), which is faster if K is large.

Comment: So I do believe the algorithm right now is finding the shortest path. i dont think its doing it by reversing the edges.

Comment: "First, run Dijkstra's algorithm starting at the target on the graph with reversed edges, to find the distance from each vertex to the target in linear time" - why dijkstra's algorithm runs in linear time

Comment: and one more moment, on each deviation-finding iteration we perform a simple graph traversal, but what's the condition for stop in that traversal? let's say we reached target node without finding any deviation. but that doesn't mean there is no deviation left. in order to find the next deviation, we need to inspect all possible paths to the target and that's exponential

Comment: @mangusta, for each of the K-1 deviation-finding iterations, we inspect all deviating edges adjacent to nodes in the trie. There are at most E of those.  We evaluate the corresponding path length of each in constant time, because we've memoized the distance from its adjacent vertex to the target.  We then only remember the deviation edge with the shortest corresponding path length.  That is the one we use to build the new path.  There is never anything inspecting all possible paths to the target from anywhere.

Comment: right, I confused trie inspection with graph traversal. but how do we construct that trie and when? let's say we have a source node A with adjacent nodes B, C and D. let's also assume that the shortest path from A to target is already in trie. you mean, on the first iteration we put A-B, A-C, A-D into the trie, then get the smallest distance to target among B, C, D (memoized ones), then what happens on second iteration?

Comment: On the first iteration you put the shortest path into the trie, say A->B->C->D.  In the trie there will be 4 nodes including root.  On the second iteration you examine divergent edge, say A->X, B->Y, and C->Z.  From the distance in trie and the distance memos, you find, for example that the shortest divergent path is through B->Y.  Add that path to the trie, starting at the point of divergence, so add for example A->B->Y->Z->D  to the trie, starting at B, because A->B is already there.